# What is the maximum number of turns (not moves) needed to solve a Rubik's Cube?

Tags: rubiks-cube

This is more than the normally quoted 20 since the normal maximum solution counts a double turn as one move. If you consider that one move can either one or two turns then what is the maximum number of turns needed to solve a Rubik's Cube?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_solutions_for_Rubik%27s_Cube) it's **26**:

> There are two common ways to measure the length of a solution. The first is to count the number of quarter turns. The second is to count the number of outer-layer twists, called "face turns". A move to turn an outer layer two quarter (90°) turns in the same direction would be counted as two moves in the quarter turn metric (QTM), but as one turn in the face metric (FTM, or HTM "Half Turn Metric", or OBTM "Outer Block Turn Metric").
>
> The minimal number of face turns needed to solve any instance of the Rubik's Cube is 20, and the minimal number of quarter turns is 26.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, in all these metrics, do they count a turn each in the same direction of opposing faces, e.g., top and bottom face, as a single center turn?

Comment: @justhalf if I interpret it correctly, those metrics don't allow center turns, just 'face' turns.

Comment: More details here: https://www.cube20.org/qtm/